# How to Join Table with Different Primary Key/ Foreign Key

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, join, primary-key

i have a problem in Stored Procedure C# about how to join 3 tables. 
For example :

Table A :
ID_Budget,Name,date

Table B :
ID_Budget,Qty,GrandTotalBudget
(Table B is detail from Table A)

Table C :
ID_Actual,GrandTotalActual

(total records in table A,table B, table C are same)

I use inner join for Table A and Table B and no problem. But, when i try to CROSS JOIN with table C, it gives repeating data. CROSS JOIN is automatic generate from C# when i add Table C in store procedure. i also try FULL JOIN but it's not worked.

In Crystal report, i wanna get data ID_Budget, GrandTotalBudget, and GrandTotalActual

I need your help,guys (or master) really ASAP

Thanks before!! :)

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?  Do you mean SQL Server?

Comment: How does Table C relate to table A and or B?

Comment: i use internal database in C#. but the query i think similar with SQL Server

Comment: That's the problem. I need how to join table A,B, and C. But in table C there's no foreign key that can be used to join with table A and table B.

Comment: You must have foregin key to join table c with other tables

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is a Cartesian Join, which will combine all rows from A and B with rows from C. To do this right, you need to have something which will connect those three tables.